# Async functions to sync

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I'm trying to run a function according to its order and just cant.
I have tried reading some question and answers but didnt understand.
How can I make the `alert("1")` happen before `alert("2");`

```
this.getCustomers = function () {
        $http
        .get('/getMessages').success(function (data,status) {
              alert("1");
              return data;
         });
         alert("2");    

    };
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code in the success function will only be executed once the getMessages request has returned a successful response. Therefore to make alert('2') occur after alert('1'), put the code after alert('1'), but still in the success function:

```
this.getCustomers = function () {
    $http
    .get('/getMessages').success(function (data,status) {
        alert("1");
        alert("2");  
     });
};
```

Comment: I edited my question - If I do it as i did the function returns null,not the data it should

Comment: What will the alerts be replaced with eventually? Does the alert('2') need access to the data, for example?

Comment: I just want to return the data - you can look at my edited question

Comment: Returning the data in this instance doesn't do anything, because the function has not been assigned to a variable; it is an anonymous function. However as you have access to the 'data' inside the function, you should be able to carry on doing whatever you need to do inside that function.

Comment: You could also look into a staple of async functionality - promises  ([this, for example](http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/)). But it's tricky to give thorough advice without knowing what you're eventually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code. It's using a watch function to wait for the first dialog to be clicked away.

Node is all non-blocking, so therefore this asynch watch will make sure the alerts are in the order you want.

```
var first = alert("1");

var stopWatching = $scope.$watch(function () {
        return first;
    }, function () { 
        alert("2");
        stopWatching();
    }, true);
```

Comment: its not working. I set first to be a function that sets a customers variable.
and instead of alert("2") i wrote `$scope.cust=getCustomers() //function to get customers`.

Comment: ok, the code I wrote was watching for a change in var first, which is happening when the first alert returns after the user clicks away the alert box. I tested this and it works.

If your function to set a customer value doesn't return anything, then var first will never change so no trigger for the second function.

Comment: If you end your function to set a customers variable with a return, for example: `return true; ` then it should hopefully work

Answer (score 0):

You could use Composable-middleware.

Example:

```
composable_middleware()
    .use($http.get('/getMessages').success(function (data,status) {
          alert("1");
          return data;
     }))
    .use(function(req,res,next) {
            alert("2"); 
    });
```

more information : https://github.com/randymized/composable-middleware

and npm link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/composable-middleware

Comment: since its in my client side i took only the js's : `composable-middleware
middleware-common-object` and added them  :
`<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/composable-middleware.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/middleware-common-object.js"></script>` but it didnt work